Why does my script using "onNewEmail(e)" fail?
Here is the script. I get errors like:

TypeError: Cannot read property "message" from undefined. onNewEmail
TypeError: Cannot call method "getFrom" of undefined. at onNewEmail

// Runs when a new email arrives in Gmail
function onNewEmail(e) {
var sender = e.message.getFrom();
var subject = e.message.getSubject();
var thread = e.message.getThread();
var date = e.message.getDate();

// Check if the email is from a certain acccount
if (sender.indexOf("xxx@gmail.com") !== -1) {
    saveEmailAsPDF(thread, subject);
    }
}

// Function to save an email thread as a PDF file
function saveEmailAsPDF(date, thread, subject) {
var pdfName = date + subject + ".pdf";
var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfName, thread.getMessages().map(function(message) {
    return message.getBody();
}).join('\n\n'), "application/pdf");
// Move the PDF file to a specific folder 
var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1VgQD-a0laSZT9sAtz1ZxxrQ4-KhSGLPI");
destinationFolder.createFile(pdfFile);
}

I tried clicking RUN, and then tried Triggers.
NOTE: I was only offered Time-based or Calendar based, so perhaps you can't trigger right when a new email arrives.
I also tried deleting the "(e)" and "e." but got the error

"ReferenceError: "message" is not defined. at onNewEmail"


It looks like you tried to run it without supplying it with a message object

Thanks- I'm new at this- any suggestion? I thought adding a trigger would cause the (e) to be replaced by the object.

There is no onNewEmail trigger. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Look at it

How do you get the idea that onNewEmail will run when a new message arrives in Gmail / that a trigger might exists for that?

When it comes to google triggers you should always keep one thing in mind.  They will never allow something to generate a trigger that doesn't require some kind of user input except for time based triggers and even then you must create the trigger either manually or programmatically.  Why not? You ask.  Because it would make them vulnerable to DDOS attacks. Which means all of our account would cease functioning.
